# Does a (complete) consistent theory have a frame?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

Suppose we have a consistent theory (that is, a set of formulas where one cannot derive false). We can assume that it's complete, if necessary. Is there a frame where all these formulas are valid? That is, does the consistency of $L$ imply $\mathsf{Frames}(L) \neq\varnothing$?

Answer (score 0):

No, in general a consistent set of sentences doesn't ever have to be validated.

For example, fix a propositional letter $p$; then $\{p\}$ is consistent but not validated in any frame. Clearly demanding completeness only makes this worse.

(OK fine, you have to require frames to be nonempty, since otherwise the empty frame validates everything; but this is part of the usual definition of frames, so that's fine.)

Comment: What does "frame" mean in this context? I'm not familiar with the terminology.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Just a Kripke frame without a valuation - so, a (nonempty) directed graph. "$K$ validates $\varphi$" means that every world of $K$ satisfies $\varphi$ under every possible valuation - so e.g. $\Diamond\Diamond p\implies \Diamond p$ is validated in exactly the transitive frames, etc. (We can also take about pointed frames, where "validates" means "makes true at the distinguished world under every valuation," but that doesn't change the situation here.)

Comment: Oh, I missed the modal logic tag! Ha.

Comment: Well, I wanted to ask something different.

Suppose we have a normal consistent logic $L$, that is, we can use 11 tautologies, the distribution axiom and three rules ($\mathsf{MP}$, $\mathsf{Sub}$, $\mathsf{Nec}$) to derive anything. Ignore completeness in my question.

I know that if some formulas are valid in a frame then everything which can be derived from them using these rules is also valid in the same frame. My question is: if $L$ is normal and consistent, is there necessary a frame which validates it? In your example one can derive $\bot$ applying the $\mathsf{Nec}$ rule to $p$.